# How to update multiple tables with one SQL statement in DB2

Tags: db2

Pseudo-code as follows:

```
update TABLEA a, TABLEB b
set a.addr = 'aaa',
b.name = 'bbb'
from TABLEA a, TABLEB b
where a.id = b.id and a.id = 1
```

Comment: Traditional SQL doesn't support multi-table UPDATE; it will likely have to be two statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only UPDATE one table. So, you can change your SQL to the following:

```
UPDATE tableA a
SET a.addr = 'aaa'
WHERE exists
     (SELECT b.id
      FROM tableB b
      WHERE b.id = a.id)
```